# Is it possible to make a "drawing" inside a form view in OpenERP?

Tags: xml, odoo

I am wondering if it would be possible in OpenERP to build a module where I will be able to draw in the form view a restaurant layout, a movie theater or a plane in order for the end user to click on a seat to make a reservation for example.

I was thinking each seat might be a button, but I am not sure I can align buttons anywhere I want.

Would this be possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default Not possible.  Some JavaScript magic development will do the work.